# Prove that (x+1)! is not O(x!)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, asymptotics, computational-complexity

Discrete math question which is as follows:

Prove that $(x+1)!$ is not $O(x!)$ using only the definition of big-O notation. (Hint!: $\log(ab) = (\log a + \log b)$)

I used a proof by contradiction saying that if it was $O(x!)$, by definition: $(x+1)! \leq (c)x!$ for $x > k$ for some $k$. This simplifies to $(x+1)(x!) \leq c(x!)$ where the factorials cancel and we get $x+1 \leq c$ for $x \gt k$ for some $k$. We can always pick an $x$ that breaks this condition no matter what. Therefore $(x+1)!$ is not $O(x!)$.

Is this correct? I did not need to use the $\log(ab)$ property at all, and therefore am skeptical.

Comment: Sure, looks correct to me.  However, you should clarify the sentence "but we can always pick an x that breaks this condition no matter what."  This could easily be written by a student who didn't actually know how to choose such an $x$.

Comment: Your argument is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is correct. Note that factorial is particularly amenable to solution using the "limit" [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition) of big-O:

$$
f(n) = O(g(n))\iff \limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{|f(n)|}{g(n)} \lt +\infty.
$$

Substituting, we get

$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{(n+1)!}{n!} = \limsup_{n\to\infty} \,(n+1) = +\infty
$$

so $(n+1)!$ is not $O(n!)$.